# How to make object follow waypoints to a center point?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence, physics

Im not sure how to approach this and looking for suggestions - I have a moving box (moved by the user) with paths cut into it, and a character that traverses the paths. The moving box moves as well as rotates.

At all times, I need the character to follow the paths (NOT walk thru walls) to get back to a point on the box that is

1. facing the screen (even when the box rotates)
2. Middle of the screen (even as the box moves up/down)

Here the circle scribble is the character:

[image]

What would this be called/any approaches? Is this a waypoint system or something more complex?

Comment: Did you check `NavMesh`?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

A nav mesh would be better if you wish to make a more complex AI for the other character say if you wanted the character to chase the player. If your route is predefined then using waypoints will be the most efficient way of creating what you want in this scenario. Here is a good tutorial by Brackeys of how to implement waypoints.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFxucZQ_5E4